# Vue.js - state updates but not DOM

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have got page editing app, where I can add pages and elements to this pages (as images or text) and like this user can have his own project.

I have slider on added pages (top-down). I click on image element from gallery, image is added to page, i add new page (that becomes active), I can still add image from gallery, but when I click show previous page and click add image, image is added to state, but not to DOM.

For every page I have prev/next buttons, page sheet (where added elements should be visible).

So after prev/next page action, add element action works fine with state, but element is not rendered.

ADD ELEMENT METHOD

```
addElement(image) {
                let newImageElement = {
                    id: uuid.v1(),
                    type: 'IMAGE_ELEMENT',
                    src: image.src,
                    width: image.width,
                    height: image.height
                }
                this.$store.dispatch('ADD_PAGE_ELEMENT', newImageElement)
            }
```

ADD ELEMENT MUTATION

```
addPageElement (state, payload) {
        let element = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(payload))
        let pageIndex = state.currentPageIndex

        state.pages[pageIndex].elements = [...state.pages[pageIndex].elements, element]
    }
```

SHOW PREV/NEXT PAGE MUTATION

```
showPrevPage (state, payload) {
        let index = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(payload))

        state.pages.map(page => {
            page.isActive = false;
        });

        state.pages[index - 1] = {...state.pages[index - 1], isActive: true}
        state.currentPage  = state.pages[index - 1].id
        state.currentPageIndex  = index - 1
    },
    showNextPage (state, payload) {
        let index = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(payload))

        state.pages.map(page => {
            page.isActive = false;
        });
        state.pages[index + 1] = {...state.pages[index + 1], isActive: true}
        state.currentPage  = state.pages[index + 1].id
        state.currentPageIndex  = index + 1
    },
```

ADD ELEMENT COMPONENT

```
<Element
                v-for="(element, index) in page.elements"
                :key="index"
                :el="element"
            />
```

[EDITED]

Rendering pages

```
<div class="pages">
        <div
            class="pages_viewport"
            id="pages_viewport"
        >
            <PageWorkSheet
                v-for="(page, index) in pages"
                :key="index"
                :isActive="page.isActive"
                :pages="pages"
                :page="page"
                :pageIndex="index"
            />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="page_new">
        <button @click="addNewPage">
            + Add new page
        </button>
    </div>
```

PageWorkSheet component

```
<div
    class="page_single"
    :class="{ 'active': pageIndex === currentPageIndex }"
    :style='{ transform: translation}'
>
    <PageData
        :pages="pages"
        :pageIndex="pageIndex"
        :page="page"
    />
    <PageSheet
        :width="width"
        :height="height"
        :bleed="bleed"
        :page="page"
    />
</div>
```

PageSheet component

```
<div 
        class="page_viewport"
        style="height: 100%; width: 100%;"
    >
        <div class="page_start_size">
            <PageBlank
                :page="page"
            />
        </div>
    </div>
```

PageBlank component

```
<div class="page_sheet">
        <div class="page_sheet-print">
            <Element
                v-for="(element, index) in page.elements"
                :key="index"
                :el="element"
            />
        </div>
    </div>
```

element component

```
<div>
            {{ el.type }}
        </div>
```

Comment: `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(payload))` this is not required. Just use `payload`.

Comment: I edited my post with page components; @The_ehT i used only payload, but it didn't do anything

Comment: Please create a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as a stack snippet or at least on jsfiddle/codepen/... Right now that's far too complex to recreate and debug this for you.

Comment: with Vue, you must be careful when manipulating arrays, since there are few ways that allow you to change an array and let Vue to track the changes: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats. In your code you're updating `state.pages[index]...` a lot. Those kind of mutation will fail to update state, see the link for reference.

Comment: @Sergeon You were right, I should not use spread operator in this case; when I changed it to Object.assign(state.pages[index - 1], { isActive: true }) it was all good

Answer (score 0):

In vue certain types of data are not reactive (such as nested data), therefore you need to manually force a rerender, in your case put a key on whatever elements are getting updated and in the function where the data is mutated change the key that will force a rerender, if you already have a key then change the existing key and it will rerender the element.